# How to pass the contents of a newcommand to answers package?

Tags: macros, expansion, exam, answers

I've got the following code, which uses [the `exam` document class](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam) and [the `answers` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/answers).  I'd like to pass the point value of the question into a separate file so that I can make use of the question's point value in a separate 'answer key' .tex file.

If I pass a literal number into the switch things work fine.

**This works great**

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}

% These provide a facility to collect up solutions/answers and grading guides into a separate file(s)
\printanswers 
\usepackage{answers}

\newcommand{\fnGradingGuide}{TempFile}

\Newassociation{sol}{Sol}{\fnGradingGuide} % ExamGradingGuideCore.tex is the intermediate file that stores stuff
\Newassociation{gradingGuide}{GradingGuide}{\fnGradingGuide}

\Opensolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide} 

% these are the macros that we'll use in the destination file to transform the things we stuff into the TempFile into something that the user will actually see
\renewenvironment{Sol}[2]{\textbf{Solution #1:\hfill#2 Points}\begin{flushleft}}{\end{flushleft}}
\renewenvironment{GradingGuide}[1]{\begin{flushleft}\textbf{Grading Guide for Question #1}\newline}{\end{flushleft}}

\newcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{30}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}


    \titledquestion{Syntax and Semantics}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Please write out what the program will print to the screen in this column} \\
    Please note that this code compiles, runs, and terminates. \

    \begin{sol}{30} <============ Note the literal '30' here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  This 30 is the points for the question
        This is the solution to question 1
    \end{sol}

    \end{questions}

    \Closesolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide}
    \centering {\Large Solutions} \\
    \input{\fnGradingGuide}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE:** This is a single-file example for simplicity, but it will still demonstrate the problem(s) I'm running into.

The contents of the extra file (`TempFile.tex`)will then contain:

**TempFile:**

```
\begin{Sol}{1}
{30} <====== THIS '30' IS THE THING I"M INTERESTED IN
^^I^^IThis is the solution to question 1
^^I
\end{Sol}
```

Now if I use a macro to define the point value (like this: `\newcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{30}`) and then pass that macro into the `sol` environment I'll get the following.

**New version, this does NOT work:**

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}

% These provide a facility to collect up solutions/answers and grading guides into a separate file(s)
\printanswers 
\usepackage{answers}

\newcommand{\fnGradingGuide}{TempFile}

\Newassociation{sol}{Sol}{\fnGradingGuide} % ExamGradingGuideCore.tex is the intermediate file that stores stuff
\Newassociation{gradingGuide}{GradingGuide}{\fnGradingGuide}

\Opensolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide} 
\renewenvironment{Sol}[2]{\textbf{Solution #1:\hfill#2 Points}\begin{flushleft}}{\end{flushleft}}
\renewenvironment{GradingGuide}[1]{\begin{flushleft}\textbf{Grading Guide for Question #1}\newline}{\end{flushleft}}

\newcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{30} % <====== This time we're using this

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}


    \titledquestion{Syntax and Semantics}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Please write out what the program will print to the screen in this column} \\
    Please note that this code compiles, runs, and terminates. \

    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}  % <======= literal 30 has been replaced by the macro/newcommand
        This is the solution to question 1
    \end{sol}

    \renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{10}
    \titledquestion{Q2}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Q2 body}

    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 2
    \end{sol}

    \end{questions}

    \Closesolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide}
    \centering {\Large Solutions} \\
    \input{\fnGradingGuide}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't work because `TempFile` contains the new command instead of the fully-expanded value of 30:

```
\begin{Sol}{1}
{\QuestionPointValue}  <================= I was hoping this would still be 30, but instead it's the new command instead
^^I^^IThis is the solution to question 1
^^I
\end{Sol}
```

When I then `include` or `input` that fragment it won't work unless `\QuestionPointValue` is already defined, then it will use that single value everywhere that `\QuestionPointValue` is found in `TempFile`

**Is there a way to define `\QuestionPointValue` so that I can use it as a 'parameter' to `TempFile`, when I finally include it in another .TeX file that will generate my answer key?**

I tried using \the in a couple of places but my nearly-blind guessing didn't work, sadly

Comment: It should be noted that the points are already stored as `\pointsofq@i` etc.  Admittedly you will need two runs and  \csname pointsofq@\roman{question}\endscname to access them.  `\@ifundefined` is also a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sol` environment tries hard to write the *exact* contents of the environment to the auxiliary file.

You can automatize your trick of using `\Writetofile`, though, by patching the definition of `\sol`.

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% These provide a facility to collect up solutions/answers and grading 
% guides into a separate file(s)
\printanswers 

\newcommand{\fnGradingGuide}{TempFile}

% ExamGradingGuideCore.tex is the intermediate file that stores stuff
\Newassociation{sol}{Sol}{\fnGradingGuide} 
\Newassociation{gradingGuide}{GradingGuide}{\fnGradingGuide}

\preto{\sol}{%
  \Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\string\QuestionPointValue{\QuestionPointValue}}%
}

\Opensolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide} 
\renewenvironment{Sol}[2]
  {\textbf{Solution #1:\hfill#2 Points}\begin{flushleft}}
  {\end{flushleft}}
\renewenvironment{GradingGuide}[1]
  {\begin{flushleft}\textbf{Grading Guide for Question #1}\newline}
  {\end{flushleft}}

\newcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{30} % <====== This time we're using this

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

    \titledquestion{Syntax and Semantics}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Please write out what the program will print to the screen in this column} \\
    Please note that this code compiles, runs, and terminates.

    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 1
    \end{sol}

    \renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{10}
    \titledquestion{Q2}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Q2 body}

    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 2
    \end{sol}

    \end{questions}

    \Closesolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide}
    \begin{center}\Large Solutions\end{center}
    \input{\fnGradingGuide}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to workaround the problem, by using a combination of commands defined in the `answer` package.
It's an ugly solution, because you need to copy and paste the same four lines: I can't manage to embed them inside a `\newcommand` or in a `\newenvironment`.

Here is the solution, the details on how it works are below.
Simply, you have to copy and paste the following four lines before each `sol` environment:

```
    \Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\pippo{\QuestionPointValue}}
    \begin{Filesave}{\fnGradingGuide}
\renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{\pippo}
    \end{Filesave}
```

Here is the whole document:

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt]{exam}

% These provide a facility to collect up solutions/answers and grading guides into a separate file(s)
\printanswers 
\usepackage{answers}

\newcommand{\fnGradingGuide}{TempFile}

\Newassociation{sol}{Sol}{\fnGradingGuide}
\Newassociation{gradingGuide}{GradingGuide}{\fnGradingGuide}

\Opensolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide} 
\renewenvironment{Sol}[2]{\textbf{Solution #1:\hfill#2 Points}\begin{flushleft}}{\end{flushleft}}
\renewenvironment{GradingGuide}[1]{\begin{flushleft}\textbf{Grading Guide for Question #1}\newline}{\end{flushleft}}

\newcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{30}

%%%%%%% THIS IS ONE IMPORTANT LINE
\let\pippo\protect

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}

%%% Q1
    \titledquestion{Syntax and Semantics}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Please write out what the program will print to the screen in this column} \\
    Please note that this code compiles, runs, and terminates. \

%% THESE ARE THE LINES YOU NEED TO COPY AND PASTE JUST BEFORE EACH sol ENVIRONMENT
    \Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\pippo{\QuestionPointValue}}
    \begin{Filesave}{\fnGradingGuide}
\renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{\pippo}
    \end{Filesave}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 1
    \end{sol}

%%% Q2
    \renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{10}
    \titledquestion{Q2}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Q2 body}


    \Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\pippo{\QuestionPointValue}}
    \begin{Filesave}{\fnGradingGuide}
\renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{\pippo}
    \end{Filesave}
    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 2
    \end{sol}

%%% Q3
\renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{50}
    \titledquestion{Q3}[\QuestionPointValue] 

    \textbf{Q3 body}
    \Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\pippo{\QuestionPointValue}}
    \begin{Filesave}{\fnGradingGuide}
\renewcommand{\QuestionPointValue}{\pippo}
    \end{Filesave}
    \begin{sol}{\QuestionPointValue}
        This is the solution to question 3
    \end{sol}

    \end{questions}

    \Closesolutionfile{\fnGradingGuide}
    \centering {\Large Solutions} \\
    \input{\fnGradingGuide}

\end{document}
```

As you can see this is the result:
[image]

### How it works?

1. It writes on the file `TempFile.tex` the definition of the `\newcommand` explicitly before each `Sol` environment.
2. In order to do so, it uses the command `Writetofile` (that writes some strings on the designated file, making the substitution of `\newcommand` commands) and the environment `Filesave` (that allows to write on the file LaTeX code as is, without making substitution of commands and so on).
3. The syntax is a bit tough to handle to do this thing, in fact, in order to define properly `\QuestionPointValue` you have to use `Filesave`, but the latter doesn't substitute the contents, so you need to define another command, called `\pippo` and define it through `\Writetofile`.
4. Though, if you use `\pippo` inside `\Writetofile` it gives error, because it tries to substitute it with it content. The only way is to put before `\protect` (as written in the documentation of `answer`) to say to `\Writetofile` that you are writing a keyword. But at the end, `\protect` remains in the definition and you are unable to correctly run `\def`.
5. So you need to define `\protect` itself, and, in order to not destroy its definition, I put the line `\let\pippo\protect` in the preamble, so as `\pippo` now is equal to `\protect` and you can redefine simply `\pippo`.

I hope this solves your problem.
Then, if you need to include `TempFile.tex` in another document, remember to define the command `\QuestionPointValue` in the preamble, otherwise the first `\renewcommand` won't recognise it.

---

### Edit

Thanks to a suggestion of [Willie Wong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507228/how-to-pass-the-contents-of-a-newcommand-to-answers-package/507278?noredirect=1#comment1281796_507278), my answer can be simplified.
As he said

> command `\Writetofile` expands the second argument twice

so you can simply write the single line:

```
\Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\QuestionPointValue{\QuestionPointValue}}
```

before each `sol` environment.

Of course you can create a command as:

```
\newcommand{\PrintPoint}[1]{\Writetofile{\fnGradingGuide}{\def\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand #1{#1}}}
```

that you can use as

```
\PrintPoint{\QuestionPointValue}
```

before each `sol` environment.

Comment: You can simplify your solution somewhat, without playing with the `\pippo` workaround. A little bit of testing shows that `\Writetofile` expands the second argument twice. So you can just write `\Writetofile{<filename>}{\def\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\QuestionPointValue{\QuestionPointValue}}` then this will write to the file `\def\QuestionPointValue{<the value of \QuestionPointValue>}`.

Comment: That's a good point, I haven't thought about it. Thank you @WillieWong for your suggestion. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Even better would be to define a command that combines your `\PrintPoint` together with the call to `\renewcommand\QuestionPointValue` in the body. (Justification: presumably each time the QuestionPointValue is to be redefined the corresponding redefinition would be needed in the solutions file.) :-)

Comment: That's actually a good idea! Moreover, an alternative would be to embed the `\PrintPoint` command inside the environment `sol`, but I have not managed to do that.